# Can I call new multiple times on static reference to a class?

Tags: java

```
class A {}

class B {
    static A someReference = null;

    void foo () {
        // does calling this function many times create new objects, or all objects will point to one memory.
        someReference = new A; 
    }
}
```

isn't making a reference static mean that it will not be able to point to new memory location.?
Thank you.

Comment: General boilerplate warning: non-final, mutable statics are a smell.

Comment: it should be `new A();` The answer is yes, as often as you call it it creates a new object and `somereference` will always point to the one created last.

Comment: isn't making a reference static mean that it will not be able to point to new memory location.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `foo()` resulting in `new A()` multiple times will create new instance of `A` every time.

However previous instance becomes eligible for garbage collection (since `someReference` is no longer pointing to it) and will be removed shortly during next garbage collection cycle.

Comment: isn't making a reference static mean that it will not be able to point to new memory location.?

Comment: @DavidPrun: not at all. It only means that there is one instance of `someReference` field per *class*, not per *object* of that class. I think you are confusing it a bit with `final` keyword

Answer (score 3):

> // does calling this function many times create new objects, or all objects will point to one memory.

Call to `new A()` always creates new Object.

When reference (`someReference`) is re-assigned to newly created object, old object may become eligible for Garbage collection.

Comment: ...and each invocation of `foo()` calls `new A()`.

Comment: isn't making a reference static mean that it will not be able to point to new memory location.?

Comment: @DavidPrun: No. If you make it as final then you can't re-assign reference. static means, variable is class scope instead of instance scope, nothing more than that.